# How to disable the "secure-file-priv" on macOS?

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench to read a .csv file, but I get this error

> Error code 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

How can I disable the "secure-file-priv" on macOS?

Comment: With a minimum effort in a search engine of your choice you would get [an answer](https://techglimpse.com/secure_file_priv-mysql-option/) within seconds. Please search first before you ask a question which has been asked and answered many times before!

Comment: This solution is actually not working, I have no my.cnf file at the specified path

Comment: It's not so easy. When I try to change my.cnf file it always crashes and I have no idea of what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

1. Open file *my.cnf*

   ```sh
   vi /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
   ```
2. Edit and save; adding one line

   ```
   [mysqld]
   secure_file_priv=''
   ```
3. Restart MySQL service

   ```sh
   mysql.server restart
   ```

Ref #[article](https://geodatawrangler.lazym8.com/blog/2017/02/16/secure-file-priv)

Answer (score 1):

If you create `/etc/my.cnf` and add `secure_file_priv = ""`, and start and stop MySQL using the MacOS control panel, assuming DMG install, the DB will start.

Comment: There is an answer there. But could you post your problem as a new question instead .

Answer (score -1):

I moved the datafile to the database directory, rather than the mysql data directory, and this solved my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34592543)